# Illegal State Exception in Mutithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime, runtime-error, illegalstateexception

I am a beginner for Core Java and I'm now studying multithreading. I have one doubt that is related to this code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
   public void run()
   {
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
           try
           {
               Thread.sleep(500);
           }
           catch(InterruptedException e)
           {
               System.out.println(e);
           }
           System.out.println(i);
       }
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       MyThread mt=new MyThread();
       MyThread mt1=new MyThread();
       mt.start();
       mt.start();
   }
}
```

The code above compiles, however I got an illegal state exception in run time. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting your first `Thread` `mt` twice, instead of starting `mt1`.

Once running, a `Thread` will throw `IllegalStateException` if you attempt to `start` it again.